# Including php file

Tags: php, mamp

I'm currently building a website using php. I'm trying to include a file named server in a file named User_Reg.php but when I try refreshing the website I get this error:

"This page isn't working. localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP Error 500"

Here is the include statement.

```
<?php include('server.php'); ?>
```

I'm using MAMP local server environment.

When I remove the include statement, my code works fine.

Comment: Check mamp error logs.

Comment: Check the Apache error log for an specific error. Most probably is PHP is not founding the file server.php, most likely because of the route to the file. The file User_Reg.php is at the same directory level that server.php?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly at the same level.

Comment: User_Reg.php is a file at root level? Or is it something impoted into, for example, index.php? If this is the case, you should put the absolute path (starting at the repository root)

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe you should debug this using the file_exists function

```
 if (file_exists($filename)) {
   echo "The file $filename exists";
 } else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
 }
```

2) Debug your code inside server.php, maybe the error is coming from that page/functions.

3) Also, Try "./server.php"